# Civicrm profile can't copy membership type value

Tags: profile

I'm using a profile to bulk update membership details including membership type.

What I want to do is to use the copy functionality to copy any changes from the first row to each row.  This works well for all fields apart from membership type.

We have three membership types: staff, student and alumni. When I change the membership type in the first row to alumni and click to copy the value to all rows, the value that is set in all the rows is 'staff' not 'alumni'.  In fact any attempt to copy the membership type value results in 'staff' being shown as the default value.

I've tried changing the order of membership types but this hasn't had any effect.

I wondered if anyone had come across anything like this before?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce that effect on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ ?  What version of Civi are you running?

Comment: Thanks Aidan for the suggestion of testing on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/
I'm running Civi 5.1.0 on WordPress.
I can replicate this on the demo site.  The demo site has the membership types, student, general and lifetime.  This time it defaults to the 'general' membership type when copied.

Comment: It looks like you've found a bug.  This isn't surprising - "Batch Update via Profile" has long been incomplete, and improvements have been made in fits and starts - e.g. I recently saw that support was added for custom fields of type "Country".  This will almost certainly need someone to write a patch.

Comment: As Jon says, looks like a bug.  Please log it on https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues

Comment: Thanks Jon and Aidan, looks like somebody already has logged it three days ago:
https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/251